# Mysql - get row without previous status

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table to keep `Sample` status.

```
 id     sample_id               previous_status     current_status  
 1      22216                   NULL                    1   
 2      22216                   1                       3   
 3      22221                   NULL                    1   
 4      22221                   1                       3
```

I want to find the Row which has no entry in current status as 1.

*Edit(from comment):*
I want the sample ids which have previous_status = 1, current status = 3 AND no row with previous_status = null, current_status = 1.

Comment: I want the sample ids which have previous_status = 1, current status = 3 AND no row with previous_status = null, current_status = 1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I want the sample ids which have previous_status = 1, current status = 3 AND no row with previous_status = null, current_status = 1

You can use correlated subquery:

```
SELECT s1.sample_id
FROM Sample s1
WHERE previous_status = 1
  AND current_status = 3
  AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1
                  FROM Sample s2
                  WHERE s2.sample_id=s1.sample_id
                    AND s2.previous_status IS NULL
                    AND s2.current_status = 1);
```

<kbd>**[`SqlFiddleDemo`](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/1c9f55/1/0)**</kbd>

---

Using `GROUP BY`:

```
SELECT sample_id
FROM Sample
GROUP BY sample_id
HAVING SUM(previous_status = 1 AND current_status = 3) > 0
   AND SUM(previous_status IS NULL AND current_status = 1) = 0;
```

<kbd>**[`SqlFiddleDemo2`](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/1c9f55/10/0)**</kbd>

Comment: `is null null` or `is not null`?

Comment: `no row with previous_status = null, current_status = 1` then according to ur jsfiddle it must be 2 records..isn't it?

Comment: @debin It is ok. I am using correlated subquery `s2.sample_id=s1.sample_id`. So it is "grouped" per sample_id not entire table.

Answer (score -1):

Try,

```
Select * from Sample where previous_status =1 and current_status = 3 and previous_status  IS NOT NULL and current_status <>1
```

where `<>` not equal to

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/1c9f55/9
(taken sqlfiddle of lad)